# JavaScript remainder (%) operator not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

I have the code below:

```
function divisibleBy(numbers, divisor){
  arr = []
  for(let i = 0 ; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
   if(numbers[i] % divisor === 0) {
      arr.push(i)
   }
  }
  return arr
}

divisibleBy([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2)
```

What I need is the code to push the number into `arr` only if the remainder of the division is 0. The expected outcome is: `[2,4,6]` however, I am getting `[1,3,5]`. As far as math is concerned, when you divide `3 by 2`, the remainder should be `1`, thus it should not be added to the array.

Comment: You're testing `numbers[i]`, but `push`ing `i`; `push` the same number you test, and it'll work. Also, side-note, the loop should be limited to `i < numbers.length`, not `i <= numbers.length`, or you test outside the available values (array indices do not include the length itself, they stop one shy of it). Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: You can also simplify your code by using [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), e.g. `function divisibleBy(numbers, divisor) { return numbers.filter(number => number % divisor === 0) }`

Answer (score 3):

`arr.push(i);` pushes the index position of the number within the `numbers` array. Change it to `arr.push(numbers[i]);` so it'll be the actual number at that index position of the `numbers` array.

```js
function divisibleBy(numbers, divisor){
  arr = []
  for(let i = 0 ; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
   if(numbers[i] % divisor === 0) {
      arr.push(numbers[i]);
   }
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(divisibleBy([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing the indexes, and not the elements. Change it to:

```js
function divisibleBy(numbers, divisor){
  arr = []
  for(let i = 0 ; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
   if(numbers[i] % divisor === 0) {
      arr.push(numbers[i])  // Push the element at index i
   }
  }
  return arr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing arr.push(i) instead of arr.push(numbers[i]) which is giving index as the output instead of the value.